# From txt file to Python dictionary

Tags: python, file, text, dictionary, compiler-construction

How can I take data from a text file in the following format:

```
abc 5
defg 8
ghi 58
jklmn 450
opqrstuv 8456
```

And add it to a dictionary. For example: the first would be dictionary['abc']=5, the last one would be dictionary['opqrstuv']=8456 and so on. I need to add all the data (every linein the text file)

Comment: By writing a Python program? Seriously, SO is not a "do my work for me" site. It is a question-and-answer site. Readers such as yourself ask specific questions and other readers try to answer them. Do you have specific programming question? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more help.

Comment: Does your input file actually contain the line `dictionary = {}`?

Comment: no..I shouldnt have put it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dictionary = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        key,value = line.split(" ")
        dictionary[key] = int(value)
```

In other words, read the file line by line, and set the dict such that each key is the area before the single space and each value is the area after that single space cast as an int.

If you'll always have `LETTERS NUMBERS` then you could do this with regex, but it seems unnecessarily difficult.

As always with dictionary mappings, try to think about what you're going to want as standard behavior if keys collide, e.g. if I read `"abc 5"` but already have `"abc 10"` earlier in the file, so `dictionary["abc"]` exists.

(If you like, here's the ugly-as-hell regex solution:

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter as iget
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    data = infile.read() # UGH
re_data = re.findall(r"([^\d\s]+)|([\d]+)", data)
dictionary = dict(zip( map(iget(0),re_data[0::2]),map(int,map(iget(1),re_data[1::2])) ))
# DOUBLE UGH. As a rule of thumb, if you're using three map
# functions in one line, REFACTOR.
```

Comment: I added an `int` conversion (and removed the now-unnecessary `strip()`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for the `int` cast. Does `int("234  \t\n\n") == int("234")`???? I had no idea.

Comment: Yes, leading/trailing whitespace is ignored. Nice feature, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        a,b = line.split()
        dictionary[a] = int(b)
```